# How to show amount on Stripe Tap to pay card reader screen in Android

Tags: android, stripe-payments, tap, tap-to-pay

I have Implemented `Stripe Tap to Pay` for `android` and I'm testing it in simulated(test) environment, It is working fine but there is an issue that I'm not able to found a way to display amount on card Reader Screen as it shows on Stripe [Docs](https://stripe.com/docs/terminal/payments/setup-reader/tap-to-pay), here is how I see the card Reader screen https://i.stack.imgur.com/OndRH.jpg.

Please help me to display amount on Card reader screen,
Thank You

Comment: Are you using SetupIntents?
The amount you set in the PaymentIntent should be visible:
Try running the demo, you should be able to see the amount in the screen same as mentioned in the docs:
github.com/stripe-samples/tap-to-pay-android-demo

Comment: I am doing the same but it not works.